# Trouble connecting to RabbitMQ/Masstransit service in Docker Swarm from .Net WebAPI

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, docker-swarm, masstransit

I'm new to using RabbitMQ/Masstransit in Docker Swarm. Having trouble connecting to the RabbitMQ service in my stack from other services (C# .Net WebAPI) in said stack. Connecting to the RabbitMQ service from outside the stack works fine.

The error message I get is:

```
Unhandled exception. System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
```

The RabbitMQ service is defined in my compose yaml as follows:

```
  rabbitmq:
    image: docker.io/masstransit/rabbitmq:latest
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    networks: 
    - smartflow_default
```

The WebAPI service is defined in my compose yaml as follows:

```
  apiexports:
    image: docker.io/renegisbertzdareit/padex.smartflow.exports:1.0.1
    ports:
      - "41003:443"
      - "42003:80"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=********
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/run/secrets/padex_solution_nl_wildcard_certificate
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+
      - LOGGING_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE="en-us"
      - LOGGING_MINIMUM_LEVEL="Debug"
      - LOGGING_FILE_PATH="/var/log/log-.json"
      - RMQ_ADDRESS="rabbitmq:5672"
      - RMQ_USERNAME="guest"
      - RMQ_PASSWORD="guest"
    networks:
      - smartflow_default
    secrets:
      - padex_solution_nl_wildcard_certificate
```

With the WebAPI .Net solution I try to connect using this code:

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(new Uri($"amqp://{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RMQ_USERNAME")}:{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RMQ_PASSWORD")}@{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RMQ_ADDRESS")}"));
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
```

Would love to get some help in figuring out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

I tried other addresses too:

```
rabbitmq:15672
rabbitmq
10.203.1.30:15672
10.203.1.30:5672
10.203.1.30
```

Comment: Stop trying to build a URI and just set the properties as shown in the [documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/transports/rabbitmq).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The issue was that I needed to add the stackname to the RMQ_ADDRESS variable. Docker compose create {stack}_{service} as the hostname.

Comment: Im guessing you actually mean `RMQ_ADDRESS`? And you shouldn't have to as docker adds both variants as dns aliases. `smartflow_default` looks like it might be a global network, in which case perhaps there was something else called rabbitmq` from some other stack on there.

Comment: Correct on the variable. I'll edit the answer. Thanks! As for the network, that is indeed a global network. I'll look into creating a seperate network for this use case.